# Porque mi proyecto con JQuery no funciona en github pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, github

Este es mi primer proyecto usando JQuery que obtiene datos desde una API y los muestra

http://codepen.io/melissa160/full/woeePB/

Funciona bien en codepen, pero cuando lo subi a github pages dejaron de funcionar las solicitudes a la API

https://melissa160.github.io/Developer-Quotes/

Si alguien conoce porque el projecto no me funciona en github pages por favor permitame saber la causa.

Gracias!

Comment: Si abres la consola de tu navegador verás el fallo que tienes - más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Seguridad/MixedContent/arreglar_web_con_contenido_mixto

Comment: ¿3 votos de cierre como demasiado amplia?

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar este tipo de errores, lo ideal es poner las URLs de los recursos sin http(s):

```
//www.animalesyanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/20081102164739-fotos-gatos.jpg
```

Así el navegador usará el protocolo correspondiente en función de si se accede a la página a través de SSL o no para cargar contenido externo.

Comment: A esto se lo conoce como protocolo relativo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Al momento de hacer lasolicitud a tu archivo .json, cambia el http por https

Comment: En vez de poner una screenshot de tu error sería más útil que nos compartieras el código que haz usado y que te lleva a causar dicho error

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, para solucionarlo intente usar este CORS proxy crossorigin.me pero me deja las solicitudes  muy lentas, si alguien conoce otra solución para el Contenido Mixto bloqueado por favor me ayuda.

Mil Gracias!